# Mask cloud shadows of Sentinel-2 L1C (TOA reflectance) in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, cloudmasking

I am trying to automate an analysis in Google Earth Engine using Sentinel-2 imagery. Sentinel-2 L2A (Bottom-of-atmosphere reflectance) imagery is not available in my study area, so I must use L1C (Top-of-atmosphere reflectance) imagery and atmospherically correct it to generate my own 2A level. Before atmospheric correction I need to remove clouds and cloud shadows pixels. I used the QA60 band of level 1C to mask the clouds, but I don't know how I can mask the cloud shadows.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Of course, I cannot use the SCL band of the L2A product or other packages like `s2cloudless` since it involves the L2A product. In case it is useful, my plan is to perform atmospheric correction afterwards using SIAC-Sensor Invariant Atmospheric Correction.

My code so far is as follows:

```
// Search criteria:
var DATE_RANGE = ['2020-10-31', '2022-10-31'];
var ROI = geometry // Draw your own geometry
print(ROI);
Map.addLayer(ROI);

// Sentinel-2 image collection:
var s2L1C = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
              .filterDate(DATE_RANGE[0], DATE_RANGE[1])
              .filterBounds(ROI);
print(s2L1C, 'Sentinel-2 L1C (raw collection)');

// Rescale values:
var scaleFactor = function(image){
  // scaleFactor is a function used to reescale images to obtain TOA-reflectance
  // for the S2_HARMONIZED (Sentinel-2 baseline 3) collection the scaling factor is 1/10000
  return image.divide(10000);
};    
var s2TOA = s2L1C.map(scaleFactor);
print(s2TOA, 'Sentinel-2 TOA-reflectance');

// Mask clouds using QA60:
function maskS2Clouds(image) {
  // Function used to mask clouds using the 'QA60' band
  // European Space Agency (ESA) clouds from 'QA60', i.e. Quality Assessment band at 60m
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}   
var s2TOAcloudFree = s2TOA.map(maskS2Clouds);
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless

Comment: @NoelGorelick thank you for your answer. COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY collection is created with `s2cloudless` using L2A imagery. `s2cloudless` also works for L1C images or only for L2A? COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY is produced globally or only in the areas with L2A products available?

Comment: s2cloudless assets in Earth Engine are produced using L1C, not L2A inputs. But the resulting mask would be applicable to both L1C and L2A.